# Page render issue - (With AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, google-chrome

I'm having a weird issue with page render while using AngularJS and Chrome.
I'm creating a cart icon that only shows when there's at least one element in my cart. The code is:

```
<a ng-style="{visibility:myCart.checkCartExistence()?'visible':'hidden'}" href="/cart"><span ng-bind="myCart.getCartQty()"></span></a>
```

Here's the problem:

Top image shows the page as soon as an article is added to the cart.
Bottom image shows the same page when you scroll down a bit.

The **cart icon** and the quantity aren't displayed immediately and **only show up when you scroll down the page**. The weirdest thing is that **if you scroll all the way up, the cart icon disappear again**.
The same happens with the title that is set dynamically, when you're at the top of the page it shows TITLE A, if you scroll down a bit it updates to TITLE B. If you scroll up it shows TITLE A again.

Unfortunately I can't post any link to the page so I'm wondering if anyone knows what this is without actually seeing the page.

**NOTE THAT:**

- This happens with Chrome.
- I tried with other browsers and *it looks like* they don't have this issue.
- I managed to make it work somehow, clearing the browser cache but it came up again soon after.

[image]

Comment: from where is it pulling in Title A or Title B? Are these text coming from any of your html views / templates?

Comment: could u also post the code for checkCartExistence method

Comment: @PaulJohn title A and title B are scope variables, checkCartExistence simply checks if my product array is not undefined

Comment: have u tried looking at the scope values while scroll up vs down - using something like http://ng-inspector.org/ ?

Comment: @PaulJohn unfortunately ng-inspector doesn't work (Not sure if it's compatible with the Angular version I'm using - the latest). Anyways it looks like everything is set but only displayed if I scroll down OR I change some CSS property trough the console.

Comment: so the variables and values are still in scope, it's just that its hidden in the DOM? The same happens when you change css as well?

Comment: @PaulJohn yes variables exist in scope and are only displayed correctly on scroll or on CSS change, like if the view isn't rendered correctly. It looks like a browser issue more than a code issue but I'm not sure about it